# Social media sharing with image preview

Tags: flutter, social-media, share-open-graph, dynamic-image-generation

I'm working on a Flutter website where I have integrated social media sharing options like Twitter, LinkedIn, WhatsApp, and Gmail. Each post on my app has an associated image, and I want to display this image preview along with the text when users share a post on social media.

I've attempted to include OG tags for image preview with Share_Plus. However, the image is not showing up. Additionally, I've used URL launcher with Twitter and LinkedIn share URLs, but the dialogs don't display my post's content.

I expected that including OG tags would enable image previews when sharing with Share_Plus. For Twitter and LinkedIn, I expected the share URLs to open dialogs with my post's specific content, including both text and image preview.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan thank you for your response. I give the details that I required, Instagram and YouTube if we share a specific post or video to WhatsApp or any other social media platform, we get a preview image of the content like that feature I want to in Flutter. If you know about it, it will be helpful. If you need more details I'm ready to give.